# UIAutomation can't access UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ui-automation

This might be a basic question, but I've searched a decent bit and read Apple's documentation as well as several questions here and a few blog posts. So far, I can't find anything to help me out.

I'm just now trying to get into UIAutomation and am having trouble with my very first screen.

I've got a UIViewController that has a UITableView that takes up most of the screen space.

I've tried a bunch of different things, but whenever I log the element tree, it seems that the UITableView is only recognized as a UIAElement with no further data available.

I can't find a way to make the UITableView "accessible" using IB. I've done the following in code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self tableView] setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
    [[self tableView] setAccessibilityLabel:@"TableView"];
}
```

Still nothing.

In Apple's documentation, the following is listed:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0];
```

Here's what I tried:

```
var firstTableView = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0];
UIALogger.logStart("Logging element tree …");
firstTableView.logElementTree();
UIALogger.logPass();
```

The result was UIAElementNil.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your table view is not loaded yet. Put in a delay, e.g. `UIATarget.localTarget().delay(3)`, and then call logElementTree to see what is going on.